# How to mock Mule ESB HTTP outbound Connector in a Functional Unit Test Case?

Tags: java, mocking, junit4, functional-testing, mule-esb

I am writing a Functional Unit test case to test a Mule Flow containing an inbound and outbound HTTP connector. The flow contains the following components:

1. An inbound HTTP connector that listens to a rest service call say http://localhost:8080/restapi/id
2. A logger that displays the id in the logs
3. A web service consumer that sends the soap request to server2 at the wsdl : http://server2:8080/sample.wsdl
4. A java component that reads recieves the output from server2 and forms the response for client.

In the functional Unit test case, I am trying to mock the HTTP outbound connector calling the serevr2.

How can I do this?

The flow configuration file code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="server2" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://server2:8080/sample.wsdl" service="sample" port="sample" serviceAddress="sample" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <flow name="samplehttpflowFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="bookmartmanager-httpListenerConfig" path="/restapi/id" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="REST request received at #[java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that you are trying to unit test? The answer is likely to depend on how you have architected your solution.

Comment: @james-wilson I have supplied the xml code for the flow. is it sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. Unfortunately this doesn't help too much in this case. The key part to your unit test is that you need to mock the HTTP requests and responses. The content of the request is interesting, however, to tell where you should introduce the mocking (and how) the import parts are how are you structuring the code that makes the request, i.e. is this in a DAO or interleaved with the business logic? As well as, what libraries are being used to make the HTTP request.